# Where Can I Find Online Examples of Cormen's Assembly-Line Scheduling?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, dynamic-programming

This is a school-related question, although not exactly homework.

I'm taking an algorithms course, currently working on Chapter 15 of [Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) book.  I've been successful at finding plenty of online examples of most of the algorithms in the book, and I can usually find some type of Java applet or other program that provides a good visualization of how the algorithms work.

An exception to that is the Assembly-Line Scheduling in Chapter 15 (Dynamic Programming).

**Does anybody know of any online resources that provide further examples or visualizations of the Assembly-Line Scheduling algorithm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck if you search for examples/visualizations of the technique rather than the specific problem... i.e. search for Dynamic Programming.

There may be some decent tutorials on TopCoder "[dynamic programming site:topcoder.com](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=en&q=dynamic+programming+site%3Atopcoder.com&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)".

Answer (score 0):

If you want the solution, I wrote one for practice. This is an example of dynamic programming. It means that your solution refrains from repetitive calculations. If a problem could be divided into subunits, and those subunits get repeated in some scenarios, then it is unnecessary to solve them more than once. In such cases you store the solution after the first time and reuse it later.

```
package com.zafar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssemblyLineProblem {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);

    int numberOfStations=scanner.nextInt();
    Station firstLine[]=new Station[numberOfStations];
    Station secondLine[]=new Station[numberOfStations];

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfStations;i++){
        firstLine[i]=new Station(i,scanner.nextInt());
        firstLine[i].setIndex(i);
        firstLine[i].setTransferCost(scanner.nextInt());
        firstLine[i].setNameOfLine("line 1");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfStations;i++){
        secondLine[i]=new Station(i,scanner.nextInt());
        secondLine[i].setIndex(i);
        secondLine[i].setTransferCost(scanner.nextInt());           
        secondLine[i].setNameOfLine("line 2");
    }
    int entryCostLine1=scanner.nextInt();
    int entryCostLine2=scanner.nextInt();
    Station beginStation=findOptimalRoute(numberOfStations, firstLine, secondLine, entryCostLine1, entryCostLine2);
    System.out.println("The optimal route is");
    print(beginStation);
    scanner.close();

}
public static void print(Station station){
    if(station==null)
        return;
    System.out.println(station.getNameOfLine()+", station "+station.getIndex()+", cost from here: "+station.getOptimalCostFromThisStation());       
    print(station.getNextOptimalStation());
}

public static Station findOptimalRoute(int numberOfStations,
        Station[] firstLine, Station[] secondLine, int entryCostLine1,
        int entryCostLine2) {
    for(int i=numberOfStations-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(i==numberOfStations-1)
        {
            firstLine[i].setOptimalCostFromThisStation(firstLine[i].getTransferCost());
            secondLine[i].setOptimalCostFromThisStation(secondLine[i].getTransferCost());
        }else{
            calculateOptimalStation(firstLine, secondLine, i);
            calculateOptimalStation(secondLine, firstLine, i);                          
        }               
    }
    if((entryCostLine1+firstLine[0].getCost()+firstLine[0].getOptimalCostFromThisStation())>= (entryCostLine2+secondLine[0].getCost()+secondLine[0].getOptimalCostFromThisStation())){
        return secondLine[0];
    }else
        return firstLine[0];

}
public static void calculateOptimalStation(Station[] currentLine, Station[] otherLine, int indexOfCurrentStation){

    int costOnContinuingOnSameLine= (currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation+1].getCost()+currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation+1].getOptimalCostFromThisStation());

    int costOnSwitchingLines=(currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation].getTransferCost()+otherLine[indexOfCurrentStation+1].getCost()+otherLine[indexOfCurrentStation+1].getOptimalCostFromThisStation()) ;
    if((costOnContinuingOnSameLine  <= costOnSwitchingLines)){
        currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation].setOptimalCostFromThisStation(costOnContinuingOnSameLine);
        currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation].setNextOptimalStation(currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation+1]);
    }
    else{
        currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation].setOptimalCostFromThisStation(costOnSwitchingLines);
        currentLine[indexOfCurrentStation].setNextOptimalStation(otherLine[indexOfCurrentStation+1]);
    }


}

}

class Station{
    private String nameOfLine;
    private int index;
    private int cost;
    private int transferCost;
    private Station nextOptimalStation;
    private int optimatCostFromThisStation=0;
    public Station(int index, int cost){
        this.index=index;
        this.cost=cost;
    }
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public Station getNextOptimalStation() {
        return nextOptimalStation;
    }
    public void setNextOptimalStation(Station nextOptimalStation) {
        this.nextOptimalStation = nextOptimalStation;
    }
    public int getTransferCost() {
        return transferCost;
    }
    public void setTransferCost(int transferCost) {
        this.transferCost = transferCost;
    }
    public int getOptimalCostFromThisStation() {
        return optimatCostFromThisStation;
    }
    public void setOptimalCostFromThisStation(int optimatCostFromThisStation) {
        this.optimatCostFromThisStation = optimatCostFromThisStation;
    }
    public String getNameOfLine() {
        return nameOfLine;
    }
    public void setNameOfLine(String nameOfLine) {
        this.nameOfLine = nameOfLine;
    }

}
```

Input:
6

7 2 9 3 3 1 4 3 8 4 4 3

8 2 5 1 6 2 4 2 5 1 7 2

2 4

Output:

The optimal route is

line 1, station 0, cost from here: 29

line 2, station 1, cost from here: 22

line 1, station 2, cost from here: 18

line 2, station 3, cost from here: 13

line 2, station 4, cost from here: 8

line 1, station 5, cost from here: 3

Other resources: https://parasol.tamu.edu/~welch/teaching/411.f14/dp.pdf